# "'MKMapRectGetWidth' has been replaced by property 'MKMapRect.width''" in Swift 5.0

Tags: swift, mapkit

I am using Apple’s [Footprint: Indoor Positioning with Core Location sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/footprint/Introduction/Intro.html) to build a mobile application. This code is in Swift 3.0, and I am converting it to Swift 5.0 syntax. 
When I run this Swift 3.0 code,

```
 let mapkitFloorplanWidth = MKMapRectGetWidth(overlay.boundingMapRect)
```

I get this error.

> *“MKMapRectGetWidth' has been replaced by property 'MKMapRect.width'”*

When I changed the syntax to

```
let mapkitFloorplanWidth = MKMapRect(overlay.boundingMapRect.width)
```

I get this error message

> *“Cannot invoke initializer for type 'MKMapRect' with an argument list of type '(Double)'”*

Please help me understand how can I get this line of code to run?

Answer (score 0):

You simply replace the use of `MKMapRectGetWidth` with the use of `width`.

```
let mapkitFloorplanWidth = overlay.boundingMapRect.width
```